# Python - Pandas - Converting column with specific subsets into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this below with Date, Price and Serial.

```
+----------+--------+--------+
|   Date   | Price  | Serial |
+----------+--------+--------+
| 2/1/1996 | 0.5909 |      1 |
| 2/1/1996 | 0.5711 |      2 |
| 2/1/1996 | 0.5845 |      3 |
| 3/1/1996 | 0.5874 |      1 |
| 3/1/1996 | 0.5695 |      2 |
| 3/1/1996 |  0.584 |      3 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

I will like to make it look like this where the serial becomes the column name and the data sorts itself into the correct date row as well as Serial column.

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|   Date   |   1    |   2    |   3    |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2/1/1996 | 0.5909 | 0.5711 | 0.5845 |
| 3/1/1996 | 0.5874 | 0.5695 |  0.584 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I understand I can do this via a loop but just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your kind help. Also curious if there is a better way to paste such tables rather than attaching images in my questions =x

Comment: Please add images to question body!

Comment: Post code/text NOT images of code or text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table`:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Serial', values='Price', aggfunc=np.sum)\
        .reset_index()

res.columns.name = ''

       Date       1       2       3
0  2/1/1996  0.5909  0.5711  0.5845
1  3/1/1996  0.5874  0.5695  0.5840
```